# Change WooCommerce Product Loop Title from H2 to H3 in Astra Theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for the help on how to change my product loop on archive page from H2 to H3 on Astra Theme.

Here's the code on my theme's function.php file.

```
function astra_woo_shop_products_title() {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_the_permalink() ) . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">';
    echo '<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">' . esc_html( get_the_title() ) . '</h2>';
    echo '</a>';
}
```

Please I need a hook to help me override this function

Answer (score 0):

Unhook to the remove the `woocommerce_template_loop_product_title` function from the `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title` hook and replace it with our own function: `astra_woo_shop_products_title`. Do this this by adding the following code to your functions.php file.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'astra_woo_shop_products_title', 10 );
function astra_woo_shop_products_title() {
    echo '<h3 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</h3>';
}
```

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for the promptp help. I installed the code as instructed, but I got this error message: Cannot redeclare astra_woo_shop_products_title() (previously declared in /home/weedonli/firearmssite.com/wp-content/themes/astra/inc/compatibility/woocommerce/woocommerce-common-functions.php:31)

Here's a link to my website: [link] (https://firearmsiste.com)